# Sonic the Hedgehog-like diagonal bouncer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D platformer game in Unity and i want have a Sonic the Hedgehog like spring, in which when you step on it, player will be bounced very high. What i have come up with so far is this.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bouncing : MonoBehaviour 
{
public Vector2 bouncingPower;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player")) 
    {
        other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2 (bouncingPower.x, bouncingPower.y);
    }
}
```

This works, but only for y-axis. I set up the force on for y and when the player is stepping on the bouncer it will be bounced high, depending on y value.

However, i also want to have bouncer be at diagonal position, so when the player collides with this kind of bouncer, the player gets thrown diagonally, but when i set up the x value aswell, it sort of works. Player only gets tilted a bit to the side and that's about it. I understand that setting these values only determines how strong would i like player to be bounced as opposed to setting the angle being thrown at.

What would be a good solution have player be thrown in, let's say, 45 degree? I would like it if the player can be bounced at x-axis only aswell, but not really a mandatory.

Comment: bouncingPower should be called something like "bouncingVector", where both x and y have max/min values between -1 and 1. You should then have a float called "bounceMultiplier", and then something like `other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = bouncingVector * bounceMultiplier` should work.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is not the best solution, indeed I would have done initially the same, put rigidbody velocity with X-Y vector.

But if you say that this do not works, you can try adding an **effector** to the "jumper".

Here is a good tutorial of how 2d effector's works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgUqhsAzGWs

Comment: could you please tell me why is not? As your link says, I provided a possible solution, with an external link which I founded by researching.